# vba excel run-time error 438 with .quit

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

> Run Time Error 438 - Object Doesn't Support this Property or Method.

Last week every things worked good, instead this week has obtained the error's popup.

Also, I have another routine that works well with the same specifics....I don't know why

However I am posting code to ask you a solution

```
   Sub ProcessFiles()    Dim Filename, Pathname As String 
    Dim wb As Workbook 


    Pathname = "C:\Users\tecnico2\Desktop\revisione prova\" 
    Filename = Dir(Pathname & "*.xlsm") 

    Do While Filename <> "" 
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Pathname & Filename) 
        DoWork wb 

        wb.Save 
        wb.Quit '<-------------- **the error appears here-**----------

        Filename = Dir() 
    Loop 
    End Sub 




    Sub DoWork(wb As Workbook) 
    With wb 
        Call AddDBFasi 
    End With 
    End Sub
```

Comment: `Workbooks` do not have a `Quit` method - `Applications` do.

Comment: Try `wb.Close` or `wb.Parent.Quit` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now every things works good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do:
You want to close the workbook? Then it's `wb.close` (if you use `wb.Close True`, it will save the workbook and you can get rid of `wb.Save`).
You want to close Excel completely?  Use `Application.Quit`